# Increasing max server memory to deal with System.OutOfMemoryException on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memory, ram

I am not very experienced so please bear with me.

I have been attempting to import a 2500 MB and 3800 MB CSV into SQL Server 2016. Unfortunately I keep getting the System.OutOfMemoryException error. My computer has 8.00 GB RAM so I figured I would just increase the max server memory from the default up to 4000 MB. For some reason though each time I try to change the max server memory to make it higher it changes back to default. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: is this similar to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042996/system-outofmemoryexception-occurs-frequently-after-upgrading-sql-server-2016-to ?

Comment: @Mark My case is not similar to that one. The error only appears when I deal with exceptionally large CSV files. Also SQL does not freeze like it does for the person in the link (nor does it slow down). Also I am unable to increase my max server memory for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it with :

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```